# What is the best way to create an infinite curry function in Javascript to allow for re-using functions partway through?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

I've created a curry function in Javascript:

```js
// fn takes two arguments: accumulator, value
function infiniteCurry(fn, startValue) {
  return function (n) {
    let acc = startValue;

    function helper(n) {
      if (n != undefined) {
        acc = fn(acc, n);
        return helper;
      }
      else return acc;
    }

    return helper(n);
  }
}

// Here's a regular old sum function
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

const curriedSum = infiniteCurry(sum, 0);

console.log(curriedSum(1)(2)(3)() == 6);
```

So far so good.

The issues come up when I try to reuse a function partway through.

```js
const add1 = curriedSum(1);
// this function should add 1 to any number, right?
console.log(add1(4)() == 5);

console.log(add1(4)() == 9); // Calling the same function again adds the 4 to the last result, which was 5.
```

Is this the way curry functions usually work?

If not, how can I make my infiniteCurry function behave more intuitively?

Comment: Your `acc` variable is held in the closure around the returned "curry" function. Thus every call to `add1()` affects that same variable.

Comment: @Pointy Is this a common way to curry?

Comment: That's not really a curry. Currying a function converts it from n-ary form to n-times unary invocations. Your function behaves *similar* by allowing infinite unary calls. Which by itself is OK, but usually currying also allows variadic calls for simplicity. At any rate, the problem is that it's actually just re-applying a binary operation. It *only* works on monoids. It's not generic - if you have a function that takes a string and a number, then a boolean, the result is not the repeat application of `op(op(str, num), boolean)` as this function would do it.

Comment: Well first, in an applicative language like JavaScript, it's not really "currying". Also, you can define the behavior however you like; there are no rules and no judgements to be pronounced. Either your tool behaves the way you want, or it doesn't, and it's up to you to "fix" it if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is this the way curry functions usually work?*
No.

*If not, how can I make my infiniteCurry function behave more intuitively?*
There's no concept of "infinite curry" in the functional paradigm. Currying is the abstraction of arity itself.

`sum` itself is not a variadic function. Consider a generic `curry2` function -

```js
const curry2 = f => a => b =>
  f(a,b)
  
const add = curry2((x,y) => x + y)
const mult = curry2((x,y) => x * y)

const add2 = add(2)
const mult2 = mult(2)

console.log(add2(5), mult2(5))
// 7 10
```

You could implement something like `$` which closely resembles the continuation functor, mapping with partially applied functions. The only "limit" to the number of `$() () () () ...` you can call is the stack size of the runtime -

```js
const curry2 = f => a => b =>
  f(a,b)

const add = curry2((x,y) => x + y)
const mult = curry2((x,y) => x * y)

const $ = x =>
  f => $(f(x))
  
$(2) (add(3)) (add(4)) (add(5)) (add(6)) (add(7)) (console.log)
// 2    + 3      + 4      + 5      + 6      + 7
// 27

$(2) (mult(3)) (mult(4)) (mult(5)) (console.log) // 120
// 2     * 3       * 4       * 5
// 120
```

Consider skipping `curry2` altogether and define your original functions in curried form. Note the final call in your variadic form is the *effect* you want. Ie, logging to the console, adding a DOM node, saving to file or database, etc -

```js
const add = x => y =>
  x + y
  
const mult = x => y =>
  x * y

const $ = x =>
  f => $(f(x))
  
$(2) (add(3)) (add(4)) (add(5)) (add(6)) (add(7)) (console.log) // 27
$(2) (mult(3)) (mult(4)) (mult(5)) (console.log) // 120
```

Using `$`, each partially applied function is immediately applied and a new `f => ...` is returned. Here's what it would look like with an *actual* continuation functor. The primary semantic difference here is all computations are delayed until `.run` is called with the effecting function -

```js
// generic functionals
const add = x => y => x + y
const mult = x => y => x * y
const comp = (f,g) => x => f(g(x))

// continuation functor
const unit = x =>
  k => k(x)
  
const map = fx => f =>
  k => fx(x => k(f(x)))

// variadic functor interface
const $ = fx =>
  ({ run: fx, map: comp($, map(fx)) })

// examples
$(unit(2))
  .map(add(3)) // computation delayed ...
  .map(add(4)) // computation delayed ...
  .map(add(5)) // computation delayed ...
  .map(add(6)) // computation delayed ...
  .map(add(7)) // computation delayed ...
  .run(console.log) // console.log(2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7)
                    // 27

$(unit(2)) .map (mult(3)) .map (mult(4)) .map (mult(5)) .run (console.log) // 120
```

Finally, we show implementing a persistent continuation functor in an object-oriented style, allowing for "infinite currying" via sequencing `.map` calls. This gives clear meaning to the programs that use it and sidesteps the need for `$` altogether -

```js
// generic functionals
const add = x => y => x + y
const mult = x => y => x * y

// continuation functor
class Cont {
  static of(x) { return new Cont(k => k(x)) }
  constructor(run) { this.run = run }
  map(f) { return new Cont(k => this.run(x => k(f(x)))) }
}

// examples
Cont.of(2)
  .map(add(3)) // computation delayed ...
  .map(add(4)) // computation delayed ...
  .map(add(5)) // computation delayed ...
  .map(add(6)) // computation delayed ...
  .map(add(7)) // computation delayed ...
  .run(console.log) // console.log(2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7)
                    // 27

Cont.of(2) .map (mult(3)) .map (mult(4)) .map (mult(5)) .run (console.log) // 120
```